# Why is the width changing?

Tags: html, css

I have hard time figure it out this piece of css, when I shrink the page one button sometimes overlaps the editbox. When I debug with firebug it shows width =0 for a container, so when I add some width button pops back to it's place. Anyway I added to the code style="width: 162px;"> but during the debugging width =0 came back after a while and button overlapped again.

How is the hard coded width being changed?

```
<div class="blocks layout-filter-box" style="width: 162px;">
   <div class="area" id="area1" style="height: 41px;">
      <label for="field1">Store Name</label>
      <span class="text">
      <input id="tab-1_NameInput" type="text" data-bind="value: Name, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/>
      <input type="text" style="visibility: hidden"/> 
      </span>
   </div>
   <div class="button-box">
      <span class="submit"><input id="tab-1_search" type="button" value="Search" /></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: probably because there is some javascript that changes it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want dynamic content to change the size of your block, try adding a `max-width` declaration to constrain it. This is telling the layout that under no circumstances should the width of this element exceed what you have defined. [Read more about max-width.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/max-width)

```
.blocks {
  max-width: 162px;
  width: 162px;
}
```

A potential downside is that your content will be cut off if you add `overflow: hidden;` unless you add `overflow-x: auto`, for example.

Comment: that will set max-width but how about min-width? do I need that too? because the block gets actually smaller not bigger.

Comment: Sorry, then yes, `min-width.`

Answer (score 0):

It has to be dynamic script like javascript. You can try to change the div's name, add css attribute "!important" or overwrite the class in javascript at the end of page (just before  tag).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ID for specific div and use it with class like given below. It will overwrite additional width set. 
check [CSS Specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

```
#blocks.blocks{
   width:162px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use max-width & min-width property to have control over that.
another thing try to use pixel-ing in dimensionsm ,margin, padding, and every thing so that resizing tha browser doesn't affect them :)